# SQL Filter Results by User

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MySQL database with one table, call it X. Users interact with X via PHP. Simple stuff. Now I would like I would like to allow each user to flag specific "rows" in X so that they don't appear when they search X in the future.

Ex. Each user is shown, say rows 1 to 10. User A doesn't want to see rows 4, 8, 9. Ever. But User B, Q and Z love those rows and just can't live without them. Oh, and we can't forget User D who hates every row but 2. And so on...

How should I go about doing this?

Update:

I should have noted: I realize I can create another table with all the rows that people don't want, but what's the best way to design the table(s) in order to support an increasing number or users and data rows?

Comment: If the user doesn't want the rows 4,8,9 - You should allow the user to  be able to remove the unwanted rows and write that option into your database. So that the next time you query it, You'll only display the ones the user had asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table called `X_blacklist`.

It will have two columns:  `userid` and `postid`. Those two columns together are the composite primary key.

For a user identified by `userid` to hide a post identified by `postid` she inserts that row into `X_blacklist`.  Then when you display items from X to your users, you do this:

```
 SELECT X.postid, X.postcontent
   FROM X
   LEFT JOIN X_blacklist ON X.postid = X_blacklist.postid AND X_blacklist.userid = ?
  WHERE X_blacklist.postid IS NULL
```

This eliminates the items from your `X` table that are mentioned in the other table for the particular user.